# Where are my error log files?

Tags: php, apache

I’m currently encountering the problem described in this
older [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php).

I notice that one of the first comments to the question suggests :"Have you checked the error logs?"

Can anyone tell me where I can find those error logs ? I am using PHP 5.4.4. with Apache 2.0 and MAMP on my Mac 10.8.5
(Also, I am using Xdebug and getting no error message from it, just getting empty $_FILES and $_POST as explained in
the abovementioned post).

This other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685949/where-can-i-find-error-logs) suggests that the answer should be "file error_log in /var/log/httpd" but I have no httpd directory in my var/log. It’s there under another name maybe ?

Comment: First thing to do: `php -i | grep error_log` If no immediate result. Locate the loaded php.ini file for the failing environment and check the value by yourself. Else consult your severs documentation

Comment: it might be `/var/log/apache2/error_log` (try with `tail /var/log/apache2/error_log`)

Comment: on my windows machine logs are in [install_directory]\Apache2\logs

Comment: Have you tried `/Applications/MAMP/logs/`

Comment: Judging from the number of downvotes, perhaps I should delete this question ? I apologize for not being very familiar with the standards here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/documentation/mamp/) for MAMP states:

4.5 Where can I find the log files?

All log files are stored in: /Applications/MAMP/logs/